# UI5 Tree Binding to JSON

Tags: sapui5

I have the following JSON file.

```
"idocs": [

{

   "Docnum": "00063463",

   "Mestyp": "MATMAS",

   "Status": "53",   

   "Sndprn": "EXTSYS1",

   "Direct": "Inbound",

   "Message": "Material 00002342 Created",

   "messages":    [{                       

             "message": "Material 00002342 Created"                              

        }],

   "segments":     [{                       

                    "segment": "E1MARAM",

                    "fields":     [{                       

                                "fieldName": "MATNR"                              

                         }]                                  

            }]                        

    }
```

I want to bind this to a tree node. I have the following code to "attempt" to do this and it is not doing anything. Not even an error.

```
var oTree = new sap.ui.commons.Tree("tree")

                                    .placeAt("idViewRoot--idViewDetail--toolBar-content");



                            oTree.bindAggregation("nodes", tgtPath, function(

                                    sId, oContext) {



                                alert("stuff");

                                var treePath = oContext.getPath();

                                var bindTextName = '';

                                if (treePath.indexOf("fields") !== -1) {

                                    bindTextName = "fieldName";

                                } else {

                                    bindTextName = "segment";

                                }

                                return new sap.ui.commons.TreeNode()

                                        .bindProperty("text", bindTextName);

                            });
```

I would appreciate if someone could take a look and point me in the right direction.

Should I see an alert "stuff" appearing, because I do not even see that. Could it be an issue with the binding.

The value of tgtPath is /idocs/0/segments.

Martin

Answer (score 0):

// data has to be tree structured

```
    var oData = {
            root:{
                name: "root",
                0: {
                    name: "item1",
                    0: {
                        name: "subitem1",
                        0: {
                            name: "subsubitem1"
                        },
                        1: {
                            name: "subsubitem2"
                        }
                    },
                    1: {
                        name: "subitem2",
                        0: {
                            name: "subsubitem3"
                        }
                    }

                },
                1:{
                    name: "item2",
                    0: {
                        name: "subitem3"
                    }
                }

            }
    };
      var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
      // set the data to the model
      oModel.setData(oData);

      var oTree = new sap.ui.commons.Tree("tree");
      oTree.setWidth("100%");
      // set the model to the tree
      oTree.setModel(oModel);

      var oTreeNodeTemplate = new sap.ui.commons.TreeNode("node");
      oTreeNodeTemplate.bindProperty("text", "name");
      oTreeNodeTemplate.setExpanded(true);

      oTree.bindAggregation("nodes", "/root", oTreeNodeTemplate);

      oTree.placeAt("body");
```

Here is sample https://jsbin.com/rexahoquso/edit?html,js,output